# Really slow performance...appears ngModelWatch is the suspect

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

Plunker of angular code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QKCd1LWhVjA47loohAom?p=info

I have some angular code that operates like so:

```
<group ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <rule ng-repeat="rule in rules">
        <tag ng-repeat="tag in tags"></tag>
    </rule>
</group>
```

I load all the data onto the page through the service. Which is about 3 groups, 15 rules, and 20+ tags.

When in google chrome my application slows down to a crawl (20 second load times on the page). When inspecting using AngularJS tools I find this ngModelWatch is the culprit. I have no $watches in my code so I can only assume this is an angular way to keep up with two way binding? But it is super slow and unsatisfactory.

[image]

Oddly enough using the latest firefox load times are only a 3 seconds for the same content.

How do i fix the ngModelWatch slowdown in Chrome?

Comment: The pic only shows 25ms costs